# Accessing Value in Nested JSON with C#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to access values in a nested json object. Here is the sample JSON

```
{
  "Content": {
    "Message": "Message Content here."
  },
  "Metadata": {
    "AS2-Properties": {
      "AS2-AgreementName": null,
      "AS2-FileName": null,
      "AS2-From": "GuestPartnerID11",
      "AS2-IsMDNSent": false,
      "AS2-MDNType": null,
      "AS2-MessageID": "1234567890",
      "AS2-MessageProcessingStatus": null,
      "AS2-OutgoingMDN": null,
      "AS2-OutgoingMDNStatus": null,
      "AS2-To": "AS2ID1"
    },
    "Message-Properties": {
      "Blob": null,
      "IsMessageInBLOB": false,
      "LogicAppRunID": "02105056416165156418945ASCA",
      "MessageDate": "2020-12-23T16:09:38.5932428Z",
      "MessageID": "7b9e2581-5a3c-42dc-a773-253164609de0",
      "MessageLength": 0,
      "MessageSource": "SomeSource",
      "PayloadType": "Exception",
      "SenderIPAddress": "00.000.000.000"
    },
    "SL360-Properties": {
      "Property1": "Value",
      "Property2": "Value"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what I have tried, I can read the message from a file and print the whole message to the console but when I try to print one value such as messageId, I get the error "Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'Program.PostMessage'

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonData = string.Empty;
            jsonData = File.ReadAllText(@"filelocation");

            Console.WriteLine(jsonData);

            PostMessage postMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostMessage>(jsonData);

            var messageId = postMessage["Message-Properties"]["MessageId"].Value<string>();

            Console.WriteLine(messageId);
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Once you deserialize to a strongly typed object, you don't access the values via indexing. You should access via dot notation. Of course, your property names need to be valid C# objects, so you may need to apply some custom attributes to go from the JSON property names (that include dashes) to the C# property names (which can't include dashes). Share your class definition for PostMessage in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your quick input Mason. I am looking up accessing values with dot notation now. I have added the class definition for post message to my original post.

Comment: Your PostMessage class doesn't match the structure of your JSON at all. Your JSON doesn't have top level string properties for MessageID and Message. It has top level properties for Content and Metadata. If you visit [Json2CSharp.com](https://json2csharp.com/) and paste in the JSON, it will tell you what the matching class structure should be, and even add the appropriate attributes so it can map from the JSON property names to valid C# names.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification and for the valuable link, I will give it a try with the appropriate class structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quite like QuickType.IO for the C# it generates when you paste JSON in:

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using SomeNamespace;
//
//    var authResponse = AuthResponse.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class AuthResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("Content")]
        public Content Content { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Metadata")]
        public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Content
    {
        [JsonProperty("Message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Metadata
    {
        [JsonProperty("AS2-Properties")]
        public As2Properties As2Properties { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Message-Properties")]
        public MessageProperties MessageProperties { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SL360-Properties")]
        public Sl360Properties Sl360Properties { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class As2Properties
    {
        [JsonProperty("AS2-AgreementName")]
        public object As2AgreementName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AS2-FileName")]
        public object As2FileName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AS2-From")]
        public string As2From { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AS2-IsMDNSent")]
        public bool As2IsMdnSent { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AS2-MDNType")]
        public object As2MdnType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AS2-MessageID")]
        public string As2MessageId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AS2-MessageProcessingStatus")]
        public object As2MessageProcessingStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AS2-OutgoingMDN")]
        public object As2OutgoingMdn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AS2-OutgoingMDNStatus")]
        public object As2OutgoingMdnStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AS2-To")]
        public string As2To { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MessageProperties
    {
        [JsonProperty("Blob")]
        public object Blob { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("IsMessageInBLOB")]
        public bool IsMessageInBlob { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("LogicAppRunID")]
        public string LogicAppRunId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("MessageDate")]
        public DateTimeOffset MessageDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("MessageID")]
        public Guid MessageId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("MessageLength")]
        public long MessageLength { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("MessageSource")]
        public string MessageSource { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("PayloadType")]
        public string PayloadType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SenderIPAddress")]
        public string SenderIpAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Sl360Properties
    {
        [JsonProperty("Property1")]
        public string Property1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Property2")]
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class AuthResponse
    {
        public static AuthResponse FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResponse>(json, SomeNamespace.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this AuthResponse self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, SomeNamespace.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

You'd use it like:

```
        string jsonData = string.Empty;
        jsonData = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\code\Projects\AS2ExceptionFunction\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\sample.json");

        var ar = AuthResponse.FromJson(jsonData);

        var messageId = ar.Metadata.MessageProperties.MessageID;

        Console.WriteLine(messageId);
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: For future people, go to https://app.quicktype.io/ and paste your json. Copy the generated code into your project. For the "You'd use it like:" part above of Caius Jard's answer, in code read your file to a json string and call the generated static method "FromJson" with that json as a parameter.